# Trouble with logic in order to count results within parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I created a large database of all my prices and all my competitor prices with date and location information.

I want to narrow my database to only the "true" competitors on a location and price basis because we charge different prices in different locations. For example, I just want the count of competitors that charge $1 below or above me.

My current code stalls and does not yield results. I think it is because of my implementation of JOIN ON.

To debug, I seperated it out and got results for my first two tables no problem. Exactly what I was going for. With the third table "TrueComps", no such luck.

It's complex as a result of joining 3 tables. I am new to SQL and am thus interested in learning new solutions. I believe there is a better solution than this:

```
WITH 
RentDotComOnly AS
(
  SELECT 
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "rent_count_clean_zip", 
    -- AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "rent_avg_price", 
    0.85*min(low_price) AS "rent_lower_bound", 
    1.15*max(high_price) AS "rent_upper_bound"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    source_type in (29,36,316) 
    AND week = '2015-07-06' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
  GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
),
AllRJData AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "all_count_clean_zip"
    --, AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "all_avg_price"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    week = '2015-07-06' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
  GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
),
TrueComps AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "true_comps"
   FROM
    archived_apartments, RentDotComOnly
   WHERE
    week = '2015-07-06' 
    AND is_house <> 1 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
    AND low_price > 10000
    GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
)

SELECT 
  distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
  TrueComps.true_comps AS "TrueComps"
FROM
  archived_apartments, TrueComps

GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip, truecomps.true_comps
ORDER BY monthlyzip
```

Original code:

```
AND (low_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound and low_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound) or (high_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound and high_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound)
```

My full code:

```
WITH 
RentDotComOnly AS
(
  SELECT 
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "rent_count_clean_zip", 
    -- AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "rent_avg_price", 
    0.85*min(low_price) AS "rent_lower_bound", 
    1.15*max(high_price) AS "rent_upper_bound"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    source_type in (29,36,316) 
    AND week = '2015-07-06' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
  GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
),
AllRJData AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "all_count_clean_zip"
    --, AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "all_avg_price"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
  GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
),
TrueComps AS
(
  SELECT
    distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(distinct apt_unique_id) AS "true_comps"
   FROM
    archived_apartments, RentDotComOnly
   WHERE
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12'
    AND is_house <> 1 
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
    AND (low_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound and low_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound) or (high_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound and high_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound)    
  GROUP BY monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip
)

SELECT 
  distinct concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
  RentDotComOnly.rent_count_clean_zip AS "RentOnly",
  AllRJData.all_count_clean_zip AS "Total",
  TrueComps.true_comps AS "TrueComps"
FROM
  archived_apartments
JOIN AllRJData 
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = AllRJData.monthlyzip
JOIN RentDotComOnly
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
JOIN TrueComps
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = TrueComps.monthlyzip

GROUP BY AllRJData.monthlyzip, archived_apartments.week, archived_apartments.clean_zip, rentdotcomonly.rent_count_clean_zip, allrjdata.all_count_clean_zip, truecomps.true_comps
ORDER BY AllRJData.monthlyzip
```

Comment: Despite my suggestion not seeming to fix the problem I can still nearly guarantee that the parentheses in the rent bounds conditions are not correct. Should you also be matching the rows on `monthlyzip` or something?

Comment: Yes, my effort is to match on monthlyzip with the JOIN ON

Comment: I think you need to do that inside `TrueComps` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a join condition in `TrueComps`:

```
FROM
    archived_apartments INNER JOIN RentDotComOnly
        ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) =
           RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
```

Comment: still no luck. sql is hard

Comment: Okay so I got results now but something is going wrong because I'm seing 5+ rows per monthlyzip instead of just a count of truecomps for a single monthlyzip. any thoughts?

Comment: Well your grouping is on three columns and I almost wrote that to join on all three (monthlyzip, week, clean_zip). I don't know what any of those mean so I'm still just throwing out guesses.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment: Because of those groupings there will be multiple rows with the same `monthlyzip` in `RentDotComOnly`. If you were only expecting a single row and you're getting a lot more then it's either because of the join or the groups.

Comment: In case you didn't realize, the join condition can be any expression. So you can put `...AND x.week = y.week AND...` in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have the parentheses wrong on the last part of the `WHERE` clause. I don't know what logic you're trying to implement but my guess to fix it is:

```
AND (
            low_price  > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
        and low_price  < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
    or      high_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
        and high_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
)
```

As you've got it written the `or`'d condition is not combined with the others and stands separate which is also likely to cause the slow-down you're seeing.

Another guess is that you're looking for an overlap in price ranges. Is it possible that you really wanted this?:

```
AND (
            low_price  <= RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
        and high_price >= RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
)
```

Comment: It's still timing out on me: "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Disk Full"

Comment: I replaced your line with 'AND ( low_price > 3000 and low_price < 4000 or high_price < 4000 and high_price > 3000' and found that maybe my logic with the JOINs is off because it still stalls.

Comment: Then it probably has something to do with the cross product of `archived_apartments` and `RentDotComOnly`. I don't really understand the relationship between those two tables/table expressions or how many rows in each. It must be pretty large.

Comment: RentDotCom is only 26k rows, archives_apartments is indeed very large.

Comment: Shawn, really appreciate your persistence here. I'm still messing around on my end and I am confident that does not address the issue. I will update the question now with my current version.